# Facebox preloader doesn't show properly

Tags: javascript, facebox

I've tried as suggested from http://groups.google.com/group/facebox/browse_thread/thread/7f9a27e078998ddb
but it still won't work.

I changed the preloader image to direct path e.g. http://example.com/css/facebox/ajax-loader.gif

Even if you go to their website http://chriswanstrath.com/facebox/ the preloader image doesn't show.

Comment: what version of the plugin you are using?

Comment: its the latest version Facebox 1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, I don't really use facebox but having a quick look at the source code, it seems that the plugin is in the process of major upgrade and still not stable (maybe the whole 1.3), here are my comments:

1. It seems that the plugin was using a CSS rounded corners boxes technique and now it's using CSS properties (but the source code still contains code from the old technique).
2. a quick *hack* I made was changing `line 106` in the facebox.js file from:
   `$('#facebox .body').children().hide().end().`
   to:
   `$('#facebox .content').children().hide().end().`

Please try it and give me your feedback, and please keep following the developer for any updates!

Comment: glad it's working and remember to follow the project on github (watch the project)